# Can't save data in mongoDB atlas

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-compass

I have MongoDB Compass for local purposes.

But for a project I want to store the data in MongoDB Atlas.

To my surprise, there is no data being stored in the Atlas, it's stored in the Compass.

I don't know how it is happening.

Answer (score 0):

##### I got your problem with MongoDB!

First You need to login your account with MongoDB atlas with the link:

- https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas/register

After creating your account follow these steps:

**STEP 1:** Go to Connect option in your dashboard page then select MongoDB Compass.

**STEP 2:** Then Select installed compass in above options  if installed otherwise select first install MongoDB compass.

**STEP 3:** Copy the URI and paste in MongoDB compass and press enter.

Then Done Now your MongoDB atlas + MongoDB Compass + Application all our connected and also paste the same URI in your application while establishing a connection between your application and database.

Hope, this will resolve your problem!